# Copying a spreadsheet into the body of an email

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that I use for work that I send out on a weekly basis. The spreadsheet itself is pretty simple, but it does contain an updating chart.

I want to set up a script that will send the spreadsheet (with included chart) as part of the body of the email. I've seen several threads no here about emailing spreadsheets as a PDF, but I can't find any about sending the sheet as the body of the email.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a matter of pulling the data you want using the [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/), then [inserting it into a message](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) as an HTML table for the [Gmail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/). The chart can be embedded by getting its contents using the [getBlob() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#getBlob()), then inserting it using the [inlineImages option](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)).